# My webview is not working. Can't find symbols?

Tags: java, android

My error is that cannot find symbol class WebViewClient, and cannot find symbol class WebChromeClient huhu i tried everything in tutorials..

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
import android.webkit.WebView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        WebView superWebView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            superWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

            superWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
            superWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            superWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            superWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

                @Override
                public void onReceivedIcon(Webview view, Bitmap icon) {
                   super.onReceivedIcon(view,icon);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/myWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

This is my first try in trying webview in android studio.. installed sdks and such.. i dont know if i missed some things..

I was supposed to view a website or google in relative layout but JAVA can't seem to find the sysmbol.. need helped thanks a lot!

Comment: try to import `import android.webkit.WebViewClient;`

Comment: and `android.webkit.WebChromeClient`

Comment: now the error is error: cannot find symbol class Webview and Bitmap :((

Comment: `android.webkit.WebView` `android.graphics.Bitmap`

Comment: already have webkit.WebView, but java still cant find the symbol

Comment: @Angela you typed `Webview` incorrectly, it's case sensitive. `WebView`

Comment: Angela can you provide a good explanation so that you can be helped. I don't understand the term symbol in codes above. Or check out here if you are begginer  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm

Comment: Hi thank you it works :))

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `onReceiveIcon()`, you should use [setWebChromeClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient).

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
        }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedIcon(WebView view, Bitmap icon) {
        super.onReceivedIcon(view, icon);
        webImage.setImageBitmap(icon);
    }
});
```